# How to start a new draft from a rejected change proposal?

Tags: support, documentation, help-center

At the very end of https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes 
it states

> Even if a change is rejected, it’s not the end. Any proposed change
>   that didn’t take effect can be used to start a new draft.
>
> [image]

I am unable to find this button/page. Did I look at the wrong places or is this documentation outdated or unclear?

Would it be reasonable to include instructions how to navigate to the shown page?

---

The review page like I see it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot is out of date. This button is now in the Documentation review queue:

> [image]

We'll update the help page soon.

Comment: I don't get. I don't see that button. Please see my edited question - I attached a screenshot of the review page like I see it. Bad Karma?

Comment: @dd4711 Ah, looks like there's a bug with permission checks when we render the button. I'm fixing it.

Comment: So, I found a bug on SO?  Wohoo! Is there a bug bounty program in place? ;)

Comment: @dd4711 The fix is live in production now. Your reward is my thanks and the satisfaction of knowing you can improve your drafts. ;)

Comment: I see it already. Good job, well done!